# replace recompiled kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I edited the source of a kernel module, recompiled it and replaced it with the path from `modinfo` of the old kernel module, then I rebooted, there was no difference, my kernel module wasn't loaded, everything worked like i didn't changed the .ko file, although the file in the path (`filename`) of `modinfo` is the same file that I've recompiled.

when I `grep` my module from `/boot/config-*` it is configured as module (=m) and not built in to the kernel (=y)

How can I replace a kernel module?
Thanks.

Comment: You have contradictory statements: *my kernel module wasn't loaded* and *everything worked like i didn't changed the .ko file*. Did you imply that you have got kernel module loaded when it was original one? Otherwise there are few directions to investigate the issue (it might be even combination of the issues).

Comment: I ment that the code that ran was the code from the unchanged kernel module even thought the unchanged kernel module file was replaced with the recompiled kernel module